# Два SQL запроса в одном

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли объединить два следующих запроса в один:

**Запрос 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM products
```

**Запрос 2:**

```
SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE product_id = products.product_id
```

**Чтобы получилось примерно следующее:**

```
$arr[0][product_id] = 1;
$arr[0][product_title] = Название товара;
$arr[0][price] = 300;
$arr[0][images][0] = картинка 1;
$arr[0][images][1] = картинка 2;
$arr[0][images][2] = картинка 3;

$arr[1][product_id] = 2;
$arr[1][product_title] = Название товара;
$arr[1][price] = 500;
$arr[1][images][0] = картинка 1;
$arr[1][images][1] = картинка 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.*, pi.* FROM products p JOIN product_images pi ON product_id = products.product_id
```

Comment: только left join. и надо понимать как результат интерпретировать - в цикле добавлять картинки к текущему продукту (product_id), ожидая нового значения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сам запрос мне понятен, а вот как все таки "результат интерпретировать - в цикле"? Это как то можно сделать в SQL запросе, или все же в цикле FOREACH нужно объединять картинки к одному товару?

Comment: @makan, да, в php в цикле пробегаете результат запроса и раскидываете картинки. добавьте сортировку по product_id, тогда картинки для каждого продукта будут идти подряд.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю!